# Python pyTelegramBotApi - бот не обрабатывает сообщение-фото

Tags: python, telebot

Бот обрабатывает текст и числа в диалоге, но при отправке фотографии не продолжает диалог

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def starter(message):
    state=dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)
    if state==config.States.s_PARCEL.value:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы остановились на вводе названия товара.")
    elif state==config.States.s_NAME.value:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы остановились на вводе имени продавца.")
    elif state==config.States.s_SURNAME.value:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы остановились на вводе фамилии продавца.")
    elif state==config.States.s_PRICE.value:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы остановились на вводе цены на товар.")
    elif state==config.States.s_PICTURE.value:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы остановились на отправке фотографии.")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите код:")
        dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_START.value)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["reset"])
def reset_query(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Перезапуск. Введите код:")
    dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_START.value)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)==config.States.s_START.value)
def user_entering_code(message):
    if not message.text=="0000":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неверный код.")
        return
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите название товара.")
    dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_PARCEL.value)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)==config.States.s_PARCEL.value)
def user_entering_parcel(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите имя продавца.")
    dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_NAME.value)
    
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)==config.States.s_NAME.value)
def user_entering_name(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите фамилию продавца.")
    dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_SURNAME.value)
    
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)==config.States.s_SURNAME.value)
def user_entering_surname(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите цену на товар.")
    dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_PRICE.value)
    
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)==config.States.s_PRICE.value)
def user_entering_price(message):
    if not message.text.isdigit():
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Некорректный ввод числового значения.")
        return
    if int(message.text)<1000:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Цена не может быть меньше 1000.")
        return
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправте фото.")
    dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_PICTURE)

    

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"],func=lambda message: dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)==config.States.s_PICTURE.value)
def user_ending(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Создание ссылки...")
    dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_START.value)



bot.polling()
```

Конкретно в блок

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"],func=lambda message: dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)==config.States.s_PICTURE.value)
def user_ending(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Создание ссылки...")
    dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_START.value)
```

бот не попадает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В user_entering_price() в параметрах функции dbworker.set_state() надо обращатся к value

```
dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_PICTURE.value)
```

а не

```
dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.s_PICTURE)
```